# How to animate the insertion sort of strings within a string grid using a timer?

Tags: arrays, delphi, sorting

I am attempting to move the strings using timers in order to animate an insertion sort within my delphi program. Can anyone offer any advice?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
current_position, index, count : integer ;
temp : string ;


begin
current_position := 0 ; //start insertion sort
repeat
current_position := current_position + 1 ; //set up pointers
index := 0 ;
while index <= current_position do
 begin
 if word[index] > word[current_position] then
  begin
  temp:= word[current_position];
   for count := current_position downto index + 1 do
    begin
    word[count]:= word[count-1]
    end;
    word[index]:= temp;
   end;
   index:= index + 1
  end;
 until current_position = 9 ;

 for current_position := 0 to 9 do
 StringGrid1.Cells[0,current_position]:= word[current_position];

end;
```

Comment: I can't see any timers in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just insert `Sleep(<milliseconds>);` and `Application.ProcessMessages;` in your code to slow it down and display the progress. That [does introduce some problems/unwanted behaviours](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/delphi-processmessages-dark-side.htm) though, so you should be careful.